# Word linker is linking words with rule different to what is specified

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to make a program that recursively links words from a list so that the 3rd last and 2nd last letter is the same as the 2nd and 3rd letter of the next word. Although my program does this for the first two words correctly, from then on it only connects words that have the same 2nd and 3rd letters only. 'used' is a list that contains the indices of used words so they are not repeated. The function takes in a starting index and works from there.

```
def linker(b):
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if b != i and i not in used:
            if words[b][-3] == words[i][1] and words[b][-2] == words[i][2]:  
    #Compares 3rd last and 2nd last letters to 2nd and 3rd letters.
                if b not in used:
                    linkedwords.append(words[b])
                    used.append(b)  #Keeps track of used value's indicies
                linkedwords.append(words[i])
                used.append(i)  #Keeps track of used value's indicies
                linker(i)    #Recursively checks matches for the next word
```

Example output for 8 letter words:
['absences', 'aceldama', 'acentric', 'acequias', 'acerated', 'acerbate', 'acerbest', 'acerbity', 'acerolas', 'acervate', 'acervuli', 'acescent', 'acetamid', 'acetated', 'acetates']

As you can see the first two terms are correct, but it then proceeds to only link words where 'ce' are the 2nd and 3rd letters. I have no idea why it is doing this as my if statement only allows words that meet the proper requirement to be appended. Any ideas?

Comment: in your function - what is `b`? and is `words` a global variable? your example seems incomplete.. please provide a sample input for the function so we can figure out what goes wrong

Comment: The full code is here https://pastebin.com/ugeWinm6 . b is an index in the list 'words' which is decided as the starting point. In the full code there is a loop that tries each word as a starting point and finds the longest list of linked words.

Comment: will you please provide a list of words for testing? I have an idea involving some graph theory, if that might help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sOXB0IPRWnF66jYZ4inzHYwJYhbaq5ig/view

Comment: You must use recursion? is it allow to not use ? cus your question is so simple.

Comment: No it doesnt have to

Comment: Also, the program works for small inputs of ~10 words but when I try use large inputs the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without recursion:

```
final_list = []
desired_pattern = (words[0][-3:-1], 0, True)
for word in words[1:]:
    if word[1:3] == desired_pattern[0]:
        if desired_pattern[2]:
            final_list.append(words[desired_pattern[1]])
        final_list.append(word)
        desired_pattern = (word[-3:-1], words.index(word), False)
    else:
        if desired_pattern[2]:
            desired_pattern = (word[-3:-1], words.index(word), True)
```

Some helps:

> `words` is your starting list
>
> `final_list` is your desired result
>
> `desired_pattern` is the expected two letters from other words

Update me if you need anything.

Comment: Although this returns a result very fast, it does not return very long final_lists. I should have specified this earlier but the aim is also to provide as long of a list as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I didn't get what you saying? can you give me your sample list? @Baguette

Comment: For example if you use this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wuJXOznM5fu4IAMQn6KEflGOOjOTmqrK/view that has over a hundred thousand words, then link words of say 8 letters, it only prints 15 linked words, when in fact a chain of over 10,000 words can be made.

Comment: The chain will start at the first two words that matching, it checks with the current existing word.

Comment: It will be nice if you give me a short input and expected output. I think there is a misunderstanding between your desires and my solution.

Comment: Your solution will work for all short inputs, however it's when the input becomes very big that it is not completely effective. One of the aims is to have the length of the linked words list be as long as possible. Although your solution goes through and connects words correctly, it is not necessarily the longest possible chain that can exist.